# Confused about TNode, Is the interface being used as an object?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

Code files here: https://venus.cs.qc.cuny.edu/~krishna/summer19/cs313/trees/

In my Data Structures class, we're studying trees and my professor gave us these two files to study.  One file TNode.java defines an interface.  The other Tree.java defines a Tree class.

What I'm not getting and confused about is where is the TNode object being defined?  Like did the interface become an object?

Comment: Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces cannot become objects, they are abstract. However you can declare objects to be of an interface type.

You won't be able to use the Tree class without any implementation of the TNode interface. However by defining this interface Tree is capable of working with any implementation that meets the guidelines defined in TNode.

Instantiating the objects is part to the implementation's job and therefore not included in either file here.